# Does Spark on Ignite use Ignite's Job Stealing if its set?

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, job-scheduling, ignite

I use spark to perform map-reduce jobs but one issue I have is that when a worker finishes its share of tasks and other workers have tasks enqueued on their task list, the empty workers just stay idle. Ignite supports Job Stealing so when a worker is idle it can take from other workers task queue.

https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/spi/collision/jobstealing/JobStealingCollisionSpi.html

IgniteRDD is an implementation of the spark RDD that runs on the Ignite cluster. I was wondering if I keep all my spark RDD map reduce code the same but run it an ignite cluster with the job stealing algorithm set and change the spark JavaRDD to IgniteRDD would it respect the job stealing settings or would it be the same as the old spark static partition to workers algorithm.

I tried searching but no definite answer yet. Also, it would take a lot of work to get the ignite stuff to test so I figured ide ask first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collision SPI (JobStealingCollisionSpi as one of available implementations) needed for Compute in Apache Ignite environment. You're right, IgniteRDD provides the same as the old spark static partition to workers algorithm. If you really need a "job stealing" algoritgm you can try to move your application to Compute API. Apache Ignite provides friendly API and allows fine-tuning. More details you can found there [https://apacheignite.readme.io](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/compute-grid)